# Tesseract ocr performance is slow

Tags: java, image-processing, tesseract, tess4j

I use wrapper tess4j for tesseract 3 to make OCR on cyrillic characters.
Before I execute image pre-processing: skewed image, remove background and noise, adjust image quality and finaly get ROI for OCR.
Image pre-processing takes 0.5-1 seconds.
But tesseract OCR process takes a long time.

How can I enhance tesseract OCR speed perfomance?

Comment: This is very  broad.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accelerate tessercat.  It refers to c++ version of tesseract.

1. Tesseract can enable parallelization of computations. See "tessedit_parallelize" variable.
2. You can use OpenCL version of tesseract.